# core file size with ulimit

Tags: command-line, bash, ulimit

My question is probably not related to Ubuntu in particular, but since my desktop running this OS, I came to this forum.

I am trying to change the core file size using `ulimit -c` command as follows:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7959
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Changing the limitation:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

Observing the result:

```
$ ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) unlimited
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7959
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 1024
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Indeed the limit is changed.
However, when I open another terminal and check the value, I still see zero value in core file size.

Questions:

1. Are changes made using `ulimit` command affect only current process, i.e. in this case the `bash`?
2. I launch a program from shell as a fore- or-background process. Does the `ulimit` change apply for new process ?
3. How can I make that all user processes are affected with this configuration ?

Comment: Did you search for it before asking? http://serverfault.com/questions/637212/increasing-ulimit-on-centos

Answer (score 16):

`ulimit` is a shell builtin, and thus only affects the current shell, and processes started by that shell:

```
$ type ulimit
ulimit is a shell builtin
```

From [`man ulimit`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/ulimit.1posix):

```
The  ulimit  utility  shall  set  or report the file-size writing limit
imposed on files written by the shell and its child processes (files of
any  size  may be read). Only a process with appropriate privileges can
increase the limit.
```

So, yes, child processes are affected.

To set limits permanently or for all processes, edit [`/etc/security/limits.conf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/limits.conf.5) and reboot. The examples in the manpage are fairly good. You just need to add something like:

```
username - core unlimited
```

Comment: Thanks. By http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/ulimit.1posix.html, Is `ulimit` also an external command besides being a bash builtin command?

Comment: @Tim quoting the page you linked to: "Since ulimit affects the current shell execution environment, it is always provided as a shell regular built-in."