# Where do I find the core dump in ubuntu 16.04LTS?

Tags: 16.04, c++

I have a C++ program that does what it is supposed to do, but there must be some problem with pointer, since it crashes at the end and creates  a core dump. My problem is that I cannot find the core file, so I cannot debug it.

I have tried

```
ulimit -c unlimited
ulimit -a
```

and now the dimension of the file is set to unlimited, but still I cannot find the core. I have tried in every folder written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2065912/2853667) but still it seems that no core file is created.

Where can I find it?

Comment: Current directory, or `/var/crash`

Comment: While true in most cases, @waltinator , it is sometimes necessary to check `/var/log/apport.log`, because modern Ubuntu versions use Apport, which can interfere with core-dumping in non-obvious ways. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/18368068/1772379 for more info.

Comment: Related: (my own Q&A): [Where do I find core dump files in Ubuntu 20.04, and how do I view and analyze the backtrace (stack trace) in one?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1349048/327339)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

In Ubuntu the core dumps are handled by [*Apport*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport) and can be located in `/var/crash/`. But it is disabled by default in stable releases.

To enable Apport, run: `sudo systemctl enable apport.service` or `sudo service apport start`.

---

To disable, run: `sudo systemctl disable apport.service` or `sudo service apport stop` in order to back to regular core dumping method. See: [How do I enable or disable Apport?](https://askubuntu.com/q/93457/78223).

To disable permanently, edit `/etc/apport/crashdb.conf` file and comment the following line:

```
'problem_types': ['Bug', 'Package'],
```

by adding a hash symbol (`#`) in the beginning of the line.

To disable crash reporting (back to normal), remove the hash symbol (the same as it was).

---

You can also check `core_pattern`, how core dumps are handled by the kernel:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c
```

So even core files are disabled by `ulimit`, `apport` will still capture the crash.

See also:

- [How to generate a core dump in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17965/55075)
- [Core dumped, but core file is not in the current directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2065912/55075)
- for macOS, see: [How to generate core dumps in Mac OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9412156/55075)

Comment: Tried `sudo service apport start` under Ubuntu 20.04, but no crash dumps appeared in `/var/crash`.

Comment: @Mikhail, solution: see my answer here: [Where do I find the core dump file in Ubuntu 20.04, and how do I view the stack trace in it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349047/where-do-i-find-the-core-dump-file-in-ubuntu-20-04-and-how-do-i-view-the-stack/1349048#1349048).

Comment: It's the opposite, I had to do `service apport stop` and then the core files appeared in the current directory.

Answer (score 18):

All the above did not worked for me...
I looked at `/var/log/apport.log:`

```
cat /var/log/apport.log
```

and I saw the file name:

```
ERROR: apport (pid 3426) Mon Nov  8 14:34:07 2021: writing core dump to core._home_guest_a_out.1000.4 ...
```

and then I search throughout all the system

```
sudo find . -name "core._home_guest_a_out.1000.4..."
```

I found the core dump in `/var/lib/apport/coredump/`

Comment: It is beyond me why the core file gets written there instead of /var/crash (which everyone and their donkey is talking about), why apport does not log the full path, where to configure this and why there is hardly anything to be found for "/var/lib/apport/coredump" via Google. What are the Ubuntu people doing there?

Comment: Agreeing with frog.ca... it shouldn't be this hard. I just spent the last hour trying to figure out how to enable and locate a simple core dump...

Answer (score 9):

For those googlin': ( in my case -- Ubuntu 16.04 and 18.04 and a custom app ) `/var/crash` was still empty, so a quick way to handle core creation ( provided that you are e.g. using [a relevant ulimit builtin setting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642656/core-file-size-with-ulimit) ) was

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core.%u.%p.%t # to enable core generation
```

and

```
systemctl restart apport # to restore default apport settings
# which, by the way, were "|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P" (without quotes)
```

---

Sources:

- https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/linux/CoreDumpsOnServers
- http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/core.5.html

Comment: Simple, straightforward, worked.

Comment: This didn't work for me without specifying a full path, e.g. `sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=/tmp/core-%e.%p.%h.%t` https://jvns.ca/blog/2018/04/28/debugging-a-segfault-on-linux/

Comment: @jtpereyda it used to be `cwd` by default ; have no idea what modern restrictions might apply (e.g. apparmor and the like), and it is probably a good hint for e.g. daemon processes anyway