# Core file not generated in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: gdb

I was trying to generate a core file in Ubuntu 18.04. My program generates a core file, but I'm not able to find it.

```
$ ./a.out
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
$ ls -lrt
total 32
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sanjay sanjay   302 Mar  4 16:38 segmentation.cpp
-rwxrwxrwx 1 sanjay sanjay 28720 Mar  4 16:47 a.out
```

Answer (score 13):

Since non-programming users can learn little from coredumps, your shell likely suppresses them by default by setting the `ulimit` value to zero:

```
$ ulimit -c
0
```

You can set the value to any non-zero size, or simply remove the limit altogether using `ulimit -c unlimited`

See `help ulimit` or refer to `man bash` for details.

Comment: already set ulimit to unlimited

Comment: But not able to find out where system generate core file

Comment: @sam it should be generated in the current directory

Comment: no its not generated in the current folder , /tmp/cores/ also

Comment: @sam *confirm* that the ulimit is set right, because I was able to, using a test program that WILL error out, generate a segv and a core dump in the working dir

Comment: @sam ALSO it's not the general `ulimit` (also set to `unlimited` in my system), its' the **coredump** `ulimit` which you get with `ulimit -c` - make sure that is 'unlimited' as well.

Comment: i have installed ubuntu on window 10 as " window subsystem for linux" .
So is this a issue why i am not able to find out core file

Comment: @sam yes it very well may be: see for example [Core dump file is unavailable #1262](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1262)

Comment: my problem is that i have tracked down the problem to crash flles being created by apport in /var/crash.  I have no problem with this behavior in general, but for a specific invocation or a command I want an actual core dump I can run gdb on without having to decode some crash file (which I'm not even equipped to do yet!)

Answer (score 0):

check out [Where do I find the core dump in ubuntu 16.04LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966407/where-do-i-find-the-core-dump-in-ubuntu-16-04lts)

> In Ubuntu the core dumps are handled by Apport and can be located in /var/crash/. But it is disabled by default in stable releases