# I can not find coredump

Tags: gcc, debugging

```
lsb_release -a

No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

***** Source ******

```
// This is a disposable program for expermentation
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int i;
char c;
int main() {
    //float now = time(NULL);
    int now = time(NULL);
    for (i = 32; i < 66; ++i){
        c = i ;
        printf("**********\n");
        printf(" %d\n",i);
        printf(" %c\n", c);
        printf("^^^^^^^^^^\n");
        //printf("Now: %f \n", now);
        printf("Now: %d \n", now);
        } /* end for */
        // The four lines below were added in hopes of creating a core dump.
        int foo = 1;
        int bar = 0;
        int result = foo/bar;
        printf("Result: %d", result);
 return (0);
} // end main..
```

************* End source ********

Ran gcc from command line.

```
.../miscplayground$ gcc -g -o foobar play.c
```

Ran compiled code.

```
miscplayground$ ./foobar
```

---

```
 32
  
^^^^^^^^^^
Now: 1605890415 
**********
 33
 !
^^^^^^^^^^
Now: 1605890415
```

****** NOTE: The mid section of the output has cut for the purpose of eleminating data not relativant
to the issue..
******************** End NOTE *************************************

```
^^^^^^^^^^
Now: 1605890415 
**********
 64
 @
^^^^^^^^^^
Now: 1605890415 
**********
 65
 A
^^^^^^^^^^
Now: 1605890415 
Floating point exception (core dumped)
(base)
```

After running "sudo updatedb" then rebooting just to be sure the database was read,
I ran

```
$ sudo locate -i coredump | grep -i foobar
[sudo] password for kindness: 
(base) kindness@kindness-Latitude-E6220:~/development/go/Go_pdf$
```

**** NOTE that no results returned. *******

Comment: Normally, the corefile would simply be named `core`, and would be produced in the current directory. What is the output of `ulimit -c`?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1123505/core-file-not-generated-in-ubuntu-18-04