# How can I view the core dump in 18.04 LTS?

Tags: apport

I am experimenting with C-pointers and I get segmentation faults and want to view the core. Following the advice at
[Where do I find the core dump in ubuntu 16.04LTS?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966407/where-do-i-find-the-core-dump-in-ubuntu-16-04lts)
doesn't work for me. Also looked at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Apport
but that is for package developers and I am not writing a package.
How can I enable it?
Next question is how to work with it, but I can perhaps take that elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

If youu want to enable Apport, run: `sudo systemctl enable apport.service` to start on every boot or `sudo service apport start` to start `apport` only for that session.

Apport itself is running at all times, however, the crash sensing component is still disabled. To enable it permanently, run the command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apport/crashdb.conf
```

and add a hash symbol `#` at the beginning of the following line:

```
'problem_types': ['Bug', 'Package'],
```

To disable crash reporting just remove the hash symbol.

Also, refer https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingProgramCrash

Comment: /var/crash is still empty after following the steps. Also cleaned /var/crash