# Can't find apport core dumps

Tags: crash, apport

I want core dumps for my crashing application, but can't find them. According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966407/where-do-i-find-the-core-dump-in-ubuntu-16-04lts) I should be using apport.

```
$> systemctl list-unit-files | grep apport                                                                                                                                           
apport-autoreport.path                     enabled        
apport-autoreport.service                  static         
apport-forward@.service                    static         
apport.service                             generated      
apport-forward.socket                      enabled
```

Looks okay, right?

```
$> cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P
```

But I don't see any core files in my current directory or `/var/crash`.

I also tried

```
$> sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core.%u.%p.%t
$> cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
core.%u.%p.%t
```

I still don't see any core files being created.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you have their files in `/var/crash`?

Comment: I had the same case. This answer works https://serverfault.com/a/970667/255314

Answer (score 1):

Have you solved this problem?
rewrite core_pattern file can solve the paoblem,like
echo "/var/crash/core.%u.%E.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern.
but i don't want rewrite core_pattern file.