# How do I find core files for my own code in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: debugging

in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966407/where-do-i-find-the-core-dump-in-ubuntu-16-04lts)

The following things are suggested:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
ulimit -a
```

to set the limit to something other than zero. It was previously 0 on my system.

No core files after segfault.

So,
`sudo systemctl enable apport.service` (though this seems distro-related, not developer related). No corefiles in `/var/crash` or working directory after that.

There's also:

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core.%u.%p.%t # to enable core generation
systemctl restart apport # to restore default apport settings
```

Nothing still.

Looking in `/var/log/apport.log` shows

```
ERROR: apport (pid 34940) Fri Dec 24 11:48:47 2021: executable does not belong to a package, ignoring
```

Oh good! Ubuntu has disabled core dumps for my own code, destroying a valuable debugging tool.

## How can get apport off my back and get core dumps for my own executable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it.

Disable apport

```
sudo systemctl disable apport
```

Then, set `kernel.core_pattern`

```
sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern=core.%u.%p.%t # to enable core generation
```

*then* change ulimit

```
ulimit -c unknown
```

Core dump is in the working directory now.

The changes don't persist past reboot (for me).

Comment: Disabling apport will persist. To make the sysctl change persist, store it in a custom file in /etc/sysctl.d. To make the ulimit change persist... I'm not sure if it's still /etc/security/limits.conf or if some systemd supersedes that :)

Comment: Without needing to reboot, once done, you can restore apport as-is with:

`sudo systemctl enable apport; sudo systemctl start apport; sudo sysctl -w kernel.core_pattern='|/usr/share/apport/apport %p %s %c %d %P %E'; ulimit -S -c 0`